# View contents of MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, web

I've got a working Java web application that has been created a long time ago by other person, and is pretty abandoned by its creator already for couple years, but has active users uploading/downloading pdf files to it.

I now need to access the database to look at its structure, so that I can migrate some files and user data in future to use in a new project being built now.

I don't have much knowledge of Java web applications and MySql, but **I have access to the server where all the project files are located**. There is a `persistence.xml` file with the url of that database and username/password in it.

**How do I actually view the contents of the database?**

Comment: Do you know anything about MySQL?

Comment: Do you have access to `phpMyAdmin` on the server? Or some other tool locally that will allow you to use the info in `persistence.xml` to get to the MySQL Database

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think tomcat or other servlet containers have phpMyAdmin installed. only my assumption.

Comment: @FarhanQasim You may be right

Comment: You could install MySQL on your PC, then basckup the server database and restore it to your local MySQL. That would probably be safer if you are a total beginner with MySQL as any accidental woopies wont damage your real database

Comment: Thanks everyone, I installed RazorSql and managed to connect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to look for in the persistence.xml is a url, type that URL into your browser or a database viewer I'm on mac and use SEQUELPRO, you should be greeted with a login box, if you use the credentials that you found within that file then you should be able to view everything.

it should look something like this

> `<property name=”javax.persistence.jdbc.url”
>   value=”jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpadb”/>  <property
>   name=”javax.persistence.jdbc.user” value=”root”/>  <property
>   name=”javax.persistence.jdbc.password” value=”password”/>  <property
>   name=”javax.persistence.jdbc.driver” value=”com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”/>`

Source: [itnext.io](https://itnext.io/connection-to-database-when-using-jpa-50ab09b4016)

If you could include the persistence.xml without the credentials that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how much this will help, but at least will help you to explore more. You can try:
Login to your remote server[using any client]

- open terminal
- type: `mysql -u root -p`
- provide password when prompted
- run: `show databases` [check if there is multiple database and identify which-one you need to work with]
- run: `use your_database_name`
- run: `show tables;`
- now run or check table entries however you like to check like `describe table-name` , `select queries` or anyway you prefer.

**Update: Alternative and easy one:**
You can use datagrip. Just add your data source and credentials and then click on your database. Super user friendly I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

You need a client that connects to your database like Toad or SQL Developer. If you have the credentials and connectivity addresses this should be easy..